# UTF8 numerate brackets

Tags: typography, unicode

I used the minus for every dash in the past and found better characters like en dash, em dash, figure dash ...

Is there any replacement for the primitive `)` in UTF8 for list numerations like the following?

> 1) You scream for icecream
>   2) I scream for icecream
>   3) We all scream for icecream

Comment: [Dupe on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13535289/2065702)

Comment: @ZachSaucier A 100% duplicate of "what brackets exists?" not what brackets are used for numeral list-elements. Did you read the question?

Comment: I haven't seen anything different from the bracket, a dot or one of the dashes you mention. I don't think there's a specific character for this one.

Comment: You almost certainly had not been using the minus (U+2212, −) for dashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unicode blocks *[Enclosed Alphanumerics](//unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2460.pdf)* and *[Enclosed Alphanumeric Supplement](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F100.pdf)* include such characters as:

- ⑦ – circled digit seven
- ⑺ – parenthesized digit seven
- ⒎ – digit seven full stop
- – digit seven comma

However, these symbols exist mostly for compatibility with encodings for CJK (East Asian) typesetting. From [the Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/latest/):

> Nearly all of the enclosed and square symbols in the Unicode Standard are considered compatibility characters, encoded for interoperability with other character sets.

This in particular implies that such combinations and similar ones like *7)* are not considered to be something that requires special encoding by the authors of the standard. Hence, the naïve approach of using the characters from *Basic Latin* is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple types of right parenthesis, I will reference [Fileformat](http://www.fileformat.info/index.htm):

[Typical](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0029/index.htm) is what is used in textual list references I've seen: `&#41;`

[image]

[Full width](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff09/index.htm): `&#65289;`

[image]

[Ornate](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fd3f/index.htm): `&#64831;`

[image]

Also [reference](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0029/browsertest.htm):

[image]

You do not mention what you're using this for and this is also based on what is built into the font.  So I would reference the font to see, in an application like Suitcase Fusion, where the character set is visible with it's called entity they've developed for.

Comment: But the question is: What is correct for lists? The typical `)`requires typically a starting `(`! So its wrong.

Comment: @PeterRader I hope that helps some but in the end it will depend on what font you're using so you will still need to test.  I know because I had an issue about a year ago where the Parenthesis for a design where out of wack and the font the client wanted had a different design for them

Comment: I think it's reasonable to conclude that the Unicode consortium has not (yet??) seen fit to introduce a disambiguating character for this particular usage.  I doubt they will, but I'm not too familiar with their procedures.

Comment: @tripleee well from past reference the `typical` is what I've seen coded for in Suitcase so if I need to reference an entity in HTML I use `&#41;`.

Comment: Note that the full-width and ornate forms should not be used outside CJK or Arabian typesetting, respectively (and even for those, I am not sure whether they are recommended).